# i want to convert "LogCat Info" data into string from my android app

Tags: java, android, logcat

I am a beginner and I just want to convert the data of this **logcat** mainactivity into string.

I am using pushbots for notifications and I want the "bigText" to be displayed on the screen.

So how am I supposed to do that?

I want to convert the data in the `logcat` into string .. as you can see the data is in capital letters . please answer as soon as possible .

I am very curious to know. and please someone refer me a good website which can help me for this , it will also be helpful . Thank You

```
07-29 20:16:03.513    9243-9243/com.example.zia_ali.demopushnotification I/MainActivity﹕ Received message >> Bundle[{BigTextStyle=true, bigText=THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO CONVERT INTO STRING, from=381853524749, message=testing BigTextStyle, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: this is the code i used for extracting the data and converting into string to show on the plain text...


Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String message1 = (String) extras.get("message");
        TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t2.setText(message1);
but its not working the way i want it to

Comment: please help :3 ......................

Comment: deadfish ??? are you there :3 are you dead ?? :3 wait you're "dead"fish so you are dead probably LOL .. :3 am i talking to  a ghost ?? :3 
just help me :3 please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v1.

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String message1 = extras.getString("bigText");
TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
t2.setText(message1);
```

---

v2.

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String bigText = null;
if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("bigText")) {
    bigText = extras.getString("bigText");
}
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
t2.setText(bigText);
```

Comment: damn that was quick :3 i am gonna try that code :v yohohohoho

Comment: that worked man .. you're awesome ... who's awesome? you're awesome ... yeaaahhhhhh thank you so much .. :v
i want to ask one more thing . my app only starts when i click on a notification . when i try to start it through the app icon on the phone it show an error "UNFORTUNATELY APP HAS STOPPED " can u tell me why ?

Comment: check my answer again, you must check if bundle is not null and contains your key

Comment: yeah that worked fine man :P ... thanks for that too .. now can you please tell me why my app show this error "UNFORTUNATELY APP HAS STOPPED " when i try to start my app without any notification??

Comment: are you there ?? :3 or you're dead again?ahh you're "dead"fish anyways LOL... what should i do with that error btw .. umm i think you're busy  .. okay i'll find myself .. thanks a lot again for helping :) come to my place if you ever visit india .. i live at nagpur i'll guide you :P have to return the favor of yours .. thanks again .take care :P